# Array of textbox values parsed via next and previous buttons

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, textbox

I've got a form in winform with a **next** and **previous** button. I have a range of numbers i stored in an array, and want to go through them via the buttons. I need help on how i would do that & a possible example. I've tried and looked everywhere but can't come to a conclusion as i've now hit a brick wall.

```
private nextButton_Clicked()
{
    int counter;

    if (counter == 0)
    {
        //content of first page
    } 
}
```

The above works for the second page only, but I need something functional and non-repetitive.

Comment: You need to show more of your work than just this.  I could write something for you based on your question, but then you wouldn't be learning anything and I wouldn't be getting paid.

Comment: @axlj I've shown it before and people complained it was too much, so decided to give a snippet this time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (pos < someArray.Count() - 1)
    {
        pos++;
        label1.Text = someArray[pos];
    }
}

private void btnPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (pos > 0)
    {
        pos--;
        label1.Text = someArray[pos];
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please consider adding an explanation to your answer.

Comment: I created a class variable pos to hold the position in the array. each click either adds or subtracts from pos and displays the array contents at that position into a label

Comment: edit your answer and add the explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a reusable way of handling this, I would break the paging logic out into a separate class.  The explanations are in-lined.  It is *very important* to note that this implementation assumes that the data you are paging can safely be enumerated many times.  Since it sounds like the data structure you are using is an array, this should be fine.

```
public class Pageable<T>
{
    //This is your array data
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _data;

    //Number of items per page
    private readonly int _pageSize;

    //The current page (1-indexed)
    private int _currentPage;

    //Calculate Total number of pages based on number of items and user defined page size
    public int TotalPages
    {
        get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)_data.Count() / _pageSize); }
    }

    //Constructor to load the data
    public Pageable(IEnumerable<T> data, int pageSize = 10)
    {
        _currentPage = 1;
        _pageSize = pageSize;
        _data = data;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> NextPage()
    {
        //increment the page
        _currentPage++;

        //make sure that the incremented value does not exceed total pages
        if (_currentPage >= TotalPages) _currentPage = TotalPages;

        return GetPage(_currentPage);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> PreviousPage()
    {
        //decrement  the page
        _currentPage--;

        //make sure the decremented value is not less than 0
        if (_currentPage <= 0) _currentPage = 0;

        return GetPage(_currentPage);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetCurrentPage()
    {
        return GetPage(_currentPage);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GoToPage(int page)
    {
        if (page <= 0)
            throw new Exception("Cannot be less than 1.");
        if (page > TotalPages)
            throw new Exception("Cannot be greater than total number of pages.");

        _currentPage = page;

        return GetPage(_currentPage);
    }

    //The page value is the value that the user would expect.  (1-indexed)
    private IEnumerable<T> GetPage(int page)
    {
        //Correct for 1-indexed page value;
        var pageIndex = page - 1;

        //Use Language Integrated Query (LINQ) to calculate the items we need
        //Skip the first Nth items (pageIndex * _pageSize))
        //Take the next _pageSize items
        return _data.Skip(pageIndex * _pageSize).Take(_pageSize);
    }
}
```

And here are a few tests using MSTest showing how this works:

```
[TestClass]
public class PageableTests
{
    private int[] _data;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        var initialData = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 1; i < 136; i++)
            initialData.Add(i);
        _data = initialData.ToArray();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CanPageNext()
    {
        var testData = new Pageable<int>(_data);
        var firstPage = testData.GetCurrentPage().ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, firstPage.First());
        Assert.AreEqual(10, firstPage.Last());

        var secondPage = testData.NextPage().ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(11, secondPage.First());
        Assert.AreEqual(20, secondPage.Last());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ReturnsFirstPageWhenPageIsNegative()
    {
        var testData = new Pageable<int>(_data);
        var firstPage = testData.GetCurrentPage().ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, firstPage.First());
        Assert.AreEqual(10, firstPage.Last());

        var secondPage = testData.PreviousPage().ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, secondPage.First());
        Assert.AreEqual(10, secondPage.Last());

        var thirdPage = testData.PreviousPage().ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, thirdPage.First());
        Assert.AreEqual(10, thirdPage.Last());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CanPreviousPage()
    {
        var testData = new Pageable<int>(_data);
        var firstPage = testData.GetCurrentPage().ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, firstPage.First());
        Assert.AreEqual(10, firstPage.Last());

        var secondPage = testData.NextPage().ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(11, secondPage.First());
        Assert.AreEqual(20, secondPage.Last());

        testData.NextPage();

        var thirdPage = testData.PreviousPage().ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(secondPage.First(), thirdPage.First());
        Assert.AreEqual(secondPage.Last(), thirdPage.Last());

        var fourthPage = testData.PreviousPage().ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(firstPage.First(), fourthPage.First());
        Assert.AreEqual(firstPage.Last(), fourthPage.Last());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CannotExcceedMaxPages()
    {
        var testData = new Pageable<int>(_data);
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            testData.NextPage();
        }
        var lastPage = testData.GetCurrentPage().ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(131, lastPage.First());
        Assert.AreEqual(135, lastPage.Last());

        var nextToLastPage = testData.PreviousPage();

        Assert.AreEqual(121, nextToLastPage.First());
    }
}
```